# Are you a Detective

Tags: number-sequence

A detective friend of yours was trying to find clues for a crime he was investigating, he was almost done but a concluding location will help you close the case.

Unfortunately your friend could only send this but he was confident you will put together the information to close in on the place.

Once you are close enough you have other clues to finish the investigation.

16,06,68,88,??,98

1047,1038,519,510,255,246,123,???,??,??

4, 6, 12, 18, 30, 42, 60, 72, ???, ???

27, 82, 41, 124, 62, 31, 94, 47, 142, 71, 214, ???

4, 7, 15, 29, 59, ???

Hint/Edit: Remember these are only clues not actual values so change of case is acceptable, though there are probably clues in the casing

Comment: This isn't actually a cryptic crossword...?

Comment: I actually wanted to tag another appropriate tag, but could not find any, can you suggest?

Comment: I think word-problem is probably a perfectly reasonable tag for this.

Comment: Edited, now I look at it, yes this is perfect

Comment: I'm still chewing this one over, but not getting very far. The only thing I've come up with is that actually, `78` doesn't particularly fit as the first answer. Can you confirm whether or not the sequence of numbers in mdc or Florian's answer(s) is correct?

Comment: No Florian's responses are not completely correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I think I stretched it a little too far, but I will try and explain each step for anyone to be clear of.

The basics, mdc32 did a good job of uncovering most of the numbers  (except the first and one in between)

> 1. 87 - look at it upside down.
> 2. 114, 57, 48 - subtract 9, divide by 2, repeat
> 3. Numbers where x+1 and x-1 are both prime. Next are 102 and 108. 
> 4. 107 - multiply by three and add one, divide by two
> 5. 117 - multiply by two and subtract one, multiply by two and add one

And then Florian took it one step forward by Using ASCII  which left us with

> Wr90 flku

Then comes the interesting part, for anyone to understand a location I thought its important to give a clue about the country.

> Which lies in the last two digits KU which is UK in reverse 
>
> Then we are left with Wr90 fl the W being in Caps was to indicate that this was the first letter.
>
> Since we know that its UK and we have a 6 letter alphanumeric code. I thought it would be fairly simple to guess that this is an UK postcode.

The difficulty may be in understanding that these digits could be ordered in any arbitrary order, however I have checked the database and there is only one postcode that can be constructed with these characters which is

> WR9 0LF

Comment: Joe cam closest with "NR9 0FL, UK"

Comment: Did he? did he change his response later?

Comment: I had [NR9 0FL](http://grab.by/BPg2) with the postcode idea (and the reversed KU for UK), but didn't think I'd need to re-arrange the letters for a valid postcode. I also checked [WR9 0FL](https://www.google.co.uk/maps/place/Worcestershire+WR9/@52.2736997,-2.1569142,12z/data=!3m1!4b1!4m2!3m1!1s0x4870e933c6d36db7:0x567f6628b8f692eb?hl=en) on Google Maps, but since it didn't give anything that felt right, I didn't bother mentioning it (especially since NR9 **had** hit an exact postcode)

Comment: ok, so lets decide now, who should get the bounty :), I know its not fair to discuss, but I am unable to come up between mdc32, Joe and Florian

Comment: Ok, since everyone built on mdc32's response, I will go with him

Answer (score 13):

> 1. 87 - read it upside down.
>  2. 114, 57, 48: minus 9, divide by 2, repeat
>  3. 102, 108:  middle of twin primes.  https://oeis.org/A014574
>  4. 107: Collatz conjecture from 27, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collatz_conjecture#Examples
>  5. 117 - times 2 minus 1, times 2 plus 1, repeat

This gives

> Wr 90 flku
>  (87 114 57 48 102 108 107 117 in ASCII)
>
>  And frankly I don't know what location this could be.  FLKU is the airport code for Kanyau, Zambia, but it would be written in uppercase.  Anyway, many 4-letter combinations are airport codes.  It is probably a coincidence.
>  87 is more correct than 78, but "Nr 90" looks better than "Wr 90"

PS: I have to give credit to mdc32 who found most of the sequences before I did.

Comment: pretty close I should say

Comment: I certainly think this deserves +1, go on, you are almost there

Comment: You said "... once you are close enough you have other clues to finish the investigation."  :-)

Comment: @skv, did it happen in southern Greece?  If so, I will post how I got it.

Comment: @Leo I think it will be in spirit to just say No

Comment: I was thinking Nr 90 might be the runway, but runways are numbered 01-36 (degrees / 10) and not straight degrees.

Comment: @skv similar to Leo above, is it Norfolk? I'll explain if so

Comment: @skv btw I just interpreted Nr90 to mean the north pole and flku to be the airport and took the midpoint which was right over southern Greece. :P pretty stumped now

Comment: I havent used any extreme complexity there just a twist, so try to think slightly less complex probably you will hit it

Comment: @skv Yes/no? Or should I post an answer then you can shoot me down there? :P

Comment: @Joe Sorry about the delay, its not Norfolk :)

Comment: Fair enough. `NR9 0FL, UK` (KU) is a postcode in Norfolk, not that it helps anyone :-)

Answer (score 8):

> 1. 78 - look at it upside down.
>  
>  2. 114, 57, 48 - subtract 9, divide by 2, repeat
>  3.  Numbers where x+1 and x-1 are both prime. Next are 102 and 138. 
>  4. 107 - multiply by three and add one, divide by two
>  5. 117 - multiply by two and subtract one, multiply by two and add one

Comment: so what's the location?

Comment: Its not so easy my friend :) this time I made it one bit harder

Comment: @mdc32 Well, the question is about finding a place :p and the patterns etc are a clue

Comment: You are on the right direction, but I guess there is some way to go

Comment: @mdc maybe they are coordinates?

Comment: 78. 114, 57, 48. 102, 138, 150. 107. 117 - so that's everything laid out... it's not ascii chars. probably a cipher of some sort - maybe try with modulo 26? it'll need to be an address or something at the end - could be lat/long.

Comment: @mdc32 but 0 would mean 'A' wouldn't it?

Comment: Shouldn't solution discussion be carried on in Meta or chat? You expose solution avenues in the comments section to the world. At least conceal it.

Comment: Perhaps 78, 114, 57, 48, 102, 138, 150, 107, 117 is another sequence by it's self, and the next few numbers will present the solution, whether it be coordinates or ascii or anything.

Comment: i though it wasn't ASCII because 150 doesn't help.. but it turns out 150 was accidentally included... have you seen the other answer?

Answer (score 3):

Upvotes to both mdc32 and Florian F's answers, as they've done the majority of the legwork on this.

From their answers, we have

> Nr 90 flku
>  FLKU is the airport code for Kanyau, Zambia
>
>  Using [OurAirports](http://ourairports.mobi/airports/FLKU/navaids.html?start=540), we can see there is an airport which you can get to by starting at Kanyau Airport and flying NR @ 90 degrees.
>  That airport is [Moela NDB](http://ourairports.com/navaids/NR/Moela_NDB_BR/#lat=-23.97445032421124,lon=-46.32683324813848,zoom=9,type=Satellite), near Rio de Janeiro in Brazil

I feel like the answer should be more obviously right that this, but it fits the clues so it's worth posting.

Comment: yes, the answer is more obviously right than this :), that's what I feel. frankly I was afraid that this would be solved within minutes

Comment: Just curious. What does NR mean in relation to flights or directions? I might just be missing something but I've never heard this.

Comment: @mdc32 I've no idea, but it looks like some kind of directions (90 degrees Magellan) and like I say, it fits the numbers. I don't know the first thing about flying, but I'm pretty handy with Google :P

Answer (score 0):

Props to everyone who got us this far. I don't know the answer, but can get a little closer.

For the first clue, 87 rotated 180 degrees is L8, so we have 'later 90 flku' flku could be the aforementioned airport, or it could be Fort Lauderdale Keiser University.

Comment: Thanks for this, but if I have to make a general observation, looking at the previous responses probably help as much as they take you in the wrong direction, if you just look and think "Simpler" then you are much more likely to hit it